# basic_string<TCHAR> doesn't allow definition outside the place it's declared

Tags: c++, winapi

okay, i'm a bit befuddled with this error. What i'm trying to do here is make a basic_string that will be either char or wchar_t when UNICODE and _UNICODE are defined (this is in WINAPI). This does work, but for some reason, i'm unable to define a function that receives a std::basic_string outside the class where it's declared. Here's an example:

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    void func(std::basic_string<TCHAR> stringInput);
};

#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

void Test::func(std::basic_string<TCHAR> stringInput)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, stringInput.c_str(), TEXT("It works!"), MB_OK);
}
```

This yields a link error, claiming the test::func was never defined. However, if i just define inside the class like this:

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    void func(std::basic_string<TCHAR> stringInput)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, stringInput.c_str(), TEXT("It works!"), MB_OK);
    }
}

#endif
```

it works fine. However, i really like to keep my declarations and definitions in separate files to avoid redefinition errors and for organization. Here's the kicker though. when i have func defined in test.cpp like before and don't define UNICODE and _UNICODE in my main.cpp, i don't get the link errors. So really, the only time i get a link error is when TCHAR becomes a wchar_t. So here's my main and the error real quick...

main.cpp

```
#define UNICODE       // this won't compile when these are defined
#define _UNICODE

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

#include "test.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Test test;
    test.func(TEXT("wakka wakka"));
    return 0;
}
```

error:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Test::func(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >)" (?func@Test@@QAEXV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _WinMain@16`

Anyone have a clue what's going on and how i might go about fixing this?

Comment: Are you actually linking *all* your object files together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think because you are putting `#define UNICODE` in `main.cpp`, the other part doesn't know about this. When `test.cpp` is compiled, `UNICODE` is not defined. You can try putting the `UNICODE` definition as project processor macro. Or in `test.h`, write `#define UNICODE` and `#define _UNICODE` before including Windows.h .

On another note, because you've included Windows.h in Test.h, you should not include it again in main.cpp .

Consider create a default project in visual studio, and use `Precompiled Headers`. This way, put such include in stdafx.h will address all your problems:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
```

Comment: Windows.h has an #ifndef #define at the top of it as well, so it will never truly be included more than once. I tend to keep dependencies to a minimum, so that on the off chance that you don't include windows before you include test.h, it will compile correctly. ANNNyway, defining it in test.h did solve the problem. I'm just curious why the compiler can see it in test.h and not in my  main.cpp . Are the .cpp files compiled before the header files or something? Also, i never really understood precompiled headers, might you have a tutorial?

Comment: Sure Windows.h has definitions to prevent being included twice. But not all headers have that. Compiler performance-wise, organization-wise, it's bad to include the same file more than once. In your original code, only main.cpp sees ``UNICODE``. So main.cpp understands that ``TCHAR`` is ``wchar_t``. However, when test.cpp is compiled, it doesn't see this, as a result, test.cpp is compiled on the basis that ``TCHAR`` equals ``char``.

Comment: Try google for explanation on precompiled headers. Here's a few links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca(v=vs.71).aspx , http://gamesfromwithin.com/the-care-and-feeding-of-pre-compiled-headers .

Comment: my problem here is, i'm kinda writing a wrapper for other people to use, where all that need be done is include a single header, which will subsequently include the rest of the wrapper. I don't exactly like the idea of it not compiling right when someone forgets to include a dependency for it in their program. Is a precompiled header project specific, or can i write one for just the wrapper and it's various dependencies, and include it along with the wrapper?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis, well it depends on how important TCHAR is to you. I mean, are you still writing program for Windows 98? If you target Windows 2000 or above, you can safely create a Unicode executable where ``UNICODE`` is always defined. This way you change your ``TCHAR`` to ``wchar_t``. Otherwise, you are relying on the ``TCHAR`` definition, which changes when ``UNICODE`` is not defined. You will have to define it anyway. Windows itself addresses this problem by providing two copies of function, one for Unicode, one for ANSI.

Comment: yeah, i've been trying to convince myself that too. i'm just gonna require them use std::basic_string<wchar_t> and be done with it. people need to get in the habit of using multi-byte character strings anyway. Thanks for your insight man.